# Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Show that $N = \underset{g \in G}{\bigcap} g^{-1}Hg$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Show that $N = \underset{g \in G}{\bigcap} g^{-1}Hg$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I'm thinking that we first prove if $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Let $c = g^{-1}ag$ and $d = g^{-1}bg$.

Then $cd = g^{-1}(ab)g \in g^{-1}Hg$.

For $c = g^{-1}ag$, we have $c^{-1} = g^{-1}a^{-1}g \in g^{-1}Hg$.

Thus $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Now I just have to show that $N$ is normal... How do I do this? If there is an intuitive explanation to this problem, I'd be very happy to hear it!

Comment: You have not yet shown $N$ is a subgroup, have you?

Comment: Notice $$gNg^{-1}=\bigcap_{h\in G}\left(ghHh^{-1}g^{-1}\right)=\bigcap_{h\in G}(gh)H(gh)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $n\in N$ and $g_1\in G$; you want to prove that $g_1^{\,-1}ng_1\in N$. You know that, for some $g_2\in G$ and some $h\in H$, $n=g_2^{\,-1}hg_2$, but then$$g_1^{\,-1}ng_1=g_1^{\,-1}g_2^{\,-1}hg_2g_1=(g_2g_1)^{-1}h(g_2g_1).$$